# how to return what error is encountered when getting parameter from ssm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I'm using lambda to run a Flask-Ask app and right now I'm having trouble retrieving data from the parameter store. When I run my function from VS it runs fine, and has no problem retrieving a parameter.

this is piece of code causing my troubles

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    try:
        URL_var = client.get_parameter(Name="URL")       
        return str(URL_var['Parameter']['Value'])
    except Exception as e:
        track = traceback.format_exc()
        return track
```

Once its actually running on AWS the problems start.
Initially the page would just timeout when I tried to retrieve or put a parameter, so I configured it so `connect_timeout` and `read_timeout` were both equal to 5, and then I put the code in a try except block. Now what I get is a stack trace that really only tells me that the function timed out.

What I need is some way to know whats going wrong when I call get_parameter so I can figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Have you increased default lambda timeout from 3 s to more? Also what does CloudWatch Log say? it should provide a detailed info on the errors or timeouts of your function.

Comment: @Marcin I increased default timeout to 5 s and the results were the same. I checked CloudWatch logs and nothing really sticks out to me as anything substantial, but I think thats because I'm not experienced with lambda.

Comment: If there is an error in lambda, it will be in the CW Logs. But make sure not to catch any exceptions in `try-except` block. If you catch them, this may explain why CW Logs don't report them.

Comment: @Sel Does your lambda have the permission to write to CloudWatch? The lack of role will stop Lambda from logging anything. Also check the CloudTrail logs for identifying the failed API calls.

Comment: @surajM This helped. When I checked cloudtrail I noticed that the new version for some reason wasnt even making an api call. When I checked an older version, I noticed that version actually had working calls, so I redeployed it and for some reason that fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sel Glad to hear. It is always a good practice to stream the CloudTrail to CloudWatch and using the CloudWatch insights to view such API failures.